# How to get the current project directory or the bin directory and move a few level up?

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory, navigation, project-folder

I have an ASP.Net MVC app, and i have some xsl files inside of the Content directory.
I've try a few methods to get directory dynamically buy keep on coming short.

So how do i get the directory to point to the Content/xsl folder?

the closest that i came to was with this:

```
this.GetType().Assembly.CodeBase
```

which only returns the project DLL, but i can't figure out how to move up a few levels from there or what .net library to use to navigate around the path.

there's no ../.. :(

Basically i want to navigate to the Content/xsl folder which is at the same level of the Bin directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28VS.90%29.aspx) for this.